# Converting ESRI SceneLayer Package (.slpk) to Wavefront .OBJ, or other common 3D modelling software format (FBX, STL, etc)?

Tags: arcgis-online, scene-layer-package

ArcGIS.com has some great Creative Commons data I'd like to work with, but the .slpk format it's available in is not well supported in the tools I use (QGIS and blender, and I can't really afford an ArcGIS licence).

How can I convert this 'ESRI SceneLayer Package' (.slpk) JSON vertex/material and texture data into a more common format, like Wavefront .OBJ, .STL or .FBX?

Answer (score 1):

Currently this is not supported
https://community.esri.com/thread/235369-converting-scene-layer-packages-to-3d-models

Comment: Thanks although I cannot mark this as answered until a solution becomes available. I've started working on a Python module to rip the assets. The i3s spec is published here for anyone else working on this problem: https://github.com/Esri/i3s-spec/blob/master/format/Indexed%203d%20Scene%20Layer%20Format%20Specification.md#indexed-scene-layer